# Do texture arrays bring performance gains

Tags: unity, opengl, textures, rendering

I have a terrain mesh in unity that uses a four-layer texture blend, at first I used a single texture (diffuse and normal), then I converted it to two texture arrays storing diffuse and normal respectively. When it runs on an android phone (snapdragon 8gen1), the GPU clock used and the texture read bandwidth have dropped significantly, but the number of times I sample the texture in the shader hasn't changed, so what's happening here?（The bottom image shows the performance data after using an array of textures, and the top shows using a single texture）
[image: single texture]

[image: texture array]

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question. "Do they have a performance gain?" — yes, you measured it for this case. Did you mean to ask "WHY or HOW do they improve performance" instead? Those might be good questions for the Computer Graphics StackExchange, since they're about understanding graphics hardware, not about how to develop a game.